# Cambiar el texto de un label en HTML usando JavaScript o Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hola amigos buenas noches, lo que pasa es que estoy tratando de cambiar el texto de un label cuando hago click en un checkbox, pero cuando quiero aplicarlo en otros labels no funciona, este es el código que uso:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
                                                                            
  <div class="checkbox">
                                                                                
    <input type="checkbox" name="opcion" id="checkbox1">
                                                                                
    <label for="checkbox1" id="changeText" onclick="changeLabel()">Añadir</label>
                                                                            
  </div>
                                                                        
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function changeLabel() {
  var uno = document.getElementById('changeText');
  if (uno.innerHTML == 'Quitar') 
    uno.innerHTML = 'Añadir';
  else uno.innerHTML = 'Quitar'; 
}
```

Comment: El JS y HTML están bien, lo más seguro es que estés tratando de usar el mismo ID para dos o más elementos, esto es una mala práctica y por encima, si lo haces, ninguno de los elementos con el mismo ID serán obtenibles

Comment: Cómo podría usar una clase? y así poder aplicarlo en cada label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usar los mismos ID en dos o más elementos es una mala práctica y se desaconseja totalmente el poner el mismo ID en varios elementos

El atributo ID es único de cada elemento por documento y no debe repetirse, de repetirse causará una *DOM Exception*

Puedes usar una clase y obtener todos los elementos con dicha clase usando `querySelectorAll`, hay más métodos, pero prefiero el nombrado debido a que nos devuelve una lista de nodos que se pueden recorrer fácilmente con `forEach`

```js
var uno = document.querySelectorAll('.changeText');
uno.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (el.innerHTML === 'Quitar') {
      el.innerHTML = 'Añadir';
    } else {
      el.innerHTML = 'Quitar'; 
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="opcion" class="checkbox">
<label for="checkbox1" class="changeText">Añadir</label>
<label for="checkbox1" class="changeText">Añadir</label>
<label for="checkbox1" class="changeText">Añadir</label>
<label for="checkbox1" class="changeText">Añadir</label>
```

No deberías hacer un `onclick`, ya que eventualmente quedará deprecado, es mejor añadir un `eventListener` por cada elemento para detectar clicks

Comment: Ufff, muchisimas gracias, creo que he venido haciendo las cosas mal, gracias por esa información y la ayuda, vale oro para mí. Soy nuevo en el mundo de JavaScript y trato de entender las cosas desde 0.